# How to start Facebook lite with an "Intent" on button click

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, android-intent, uri

If I want to open the normal Facebook app I can use "fb://" as string uri like this:

```
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://")
```

Now I want to know what uri I can use to specifically start Facebook lite I already tried suggestions like "fb://facewebmodal" but this still open the normal app
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.lite"));
```

Hope it works for you!